# npm install axios has ssl3_get_record error

Tags: vue.js, npm, proxy, axios

there, I currently want to use npm install vue and axios. My computer was behind proxy, I also set the proxy. but still can't work. 
Here is the work i have done:

```
npm install axios
```

and then i get this kind of error

```
[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ npm install axios
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: write EPROTO 139889298220864:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yliu/.npm/_logs/2020-03-16T18_27_02_693Z-debug.log
```

and the log it show like this :

```
[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ cat /home/yliu/.npm/_logs/2020-03-16T18_27_02_693Z-debug.log | nl | tail -n 10
    24  12 verbose stack     at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:790:10)
    25  13 verbose cwd /home/yliu
    26  14 verbose Linux 4.18.0-80.1.2.el8_0.x86_64
    27  15 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "axios"
    28  16 verbose node v10.14.1
    29  17 verbose npm  v6.4.1
    30  18 error code EPROTO
    31  19 error errno EPROTO
    32  20 error request to http://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: write EPROTO 139889298220864:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
    33  21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

set the proxy (for privacy didn't put my real proxy server):

```
 npm config set http-proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080
 npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.example.com:8080
```

and show it

```
[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v10.14.1 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/yliu/.npmrc
http-proxy = "http://proxy.example.com:8080"
https-proxy = "https://proxy.example.com:8080/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; cwd = /home/yliu
; HOME = /home/yliu
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

I appropriate if anyone can give me some advices.

Thanks in advance!